# User.find() returns empty response in mongodb express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, next.js

I'm working with nextjs and express .I'm implementing simple signin form.I'm sending user credential and using find() ,checking whether user exist or not.but find() returns empty response.
In terminal find() returns array of that record.

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const schema = mongoose.Schema

const user = new schema({
    username: { type: String} ,
    password: { type: String},
    role: { type: String},
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

router.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const user = require('../models/user');
router.post('/user/signin', (req, res) => {
    user.find({
        username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password
    }, (err, user) => {
        console.log(user);
        if (err) {
            result.status(404).send({ error: 'There is some error' });
        } else if (user.length == 1) {
            var token = 'kkl';//token
            res.send({ token });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.send('Incorrect Email and Password');
        }
    });
})
module.exports = router;
```

this.is my index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production' //true false
const nextApp = next({ dev })
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler() //part of next config
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const router = express.Router();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    const app = express();
    const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/knowledgeBase')
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use('/knowledgeBase', require('./routes/router'));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res) // for all the react stuff
    })
    app.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
    })
})
```

please help

Comment: Why not use `findOne()` ?? instead.You are looking for one user right?.Find will unnecessarily traverse all the documents ,extending your response time

Comment: Your code seems fine ,are you sure that data for particular username exists??.May be try `console.log(req.body.username)` to see if the username is there.

Comment: @Shubh  Tried findOne() returns null

Comment: That clearly signifies that data for that username is not there in mongodb

Comment: @Shubh but when I tried in terminal its sends array

Comment: Is your req.body have username and password?  Can you console.log(req.body) ?

Comment: yes i have req.body

Comment: What is inside req.body? Also do you keep user passwords crypted in mongodb?

Comment: inside req.body only  username and password

Comment: I sent a temporary answer, can you try and comment what was the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What response you get when you try this? 
According to the response I will edit response.

```
router.post("/user/signin", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.username) return res.status(400).send("username cannot be null");

  if (!req.body.password) return res.status(400).send("Password  cannot be null");

  const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username});

  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User not found");

  if (req.body.password!== user.password)
    return res.status(400).send("Invalid password.");

  res.send("logined");
});
```

Comment: it returns usename cannot be null

Comment: @Karthi  Sorry I made a mistake in code, can you try with the updated code?

Comment: returns user not found

Comment: @Karthi It means there is no user with the req.body.username. Please check if your collection has this username. And also be sure whether you are controlling the db which your app uses.

Comment: It is there .I tried with terminal ,there it returns the array.how to check which db Im using .

Comment: I didn't get.I have pasted my server index.js .can u check once whether it is correct

Comment: If user not found,  it is sure that in your user collection, there is no user with that username. Please recheck your collection. MongoDb compass is a gui for mongodb. You can download it from: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/compass

Comment: I have compass.there is user with that username

Comment: Did you used this db url when connecting to the compass?
mongodb://localhost:27017/knowledgeBase

Also do you check whether if username has spaces at the end, and if it is the same as req.body.username (uppercase-lowercase also may impact)

Comment: No,  you are hitting the route correctly, and getting answer. Please copy your username in  db and req.body.username in a text editor, and compare.

Comment: compared .no changes both are identical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200592/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-karthi).

Comment: I think its not identifying database.